# How to change memory per node for apache spark worker

Tags: memory, cluster-computing, config, apache-spark

I am configuring an Apache Spark cluster.

When I run the cluster with 1 master and 3 slaves, I see this on the master monitor page:

```
Memory
2.0 GB (512.0 MB Used)
2.0 GB (512.0 MB Used)
6.0 GB (512.0 MB Used)
```

I want to increase the used memory for the workers but I could not find the right config for this. I have changed **spark-env.sh** as below:

```
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=6g
export SPARK_MEM=6g
export SPARK_DAEMON_MEMORY=6g
export SPARK_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.executor.memory=6g"
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms6G -Xmx6G"
```

But the used memory is still the same. What should I do to change used memory?

Comment: Sorry for the not good question. I find that I want to change the memory for executors. Now, the executor only use `2.0 GB (512.0 MB Used)`. How to increase the memory by changing config or system environment?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When using 1.0.0+ and using spark-shell or spark-submit, use the `--executor-memory` option. E.g.

```
spark-shell --executor-memory 8G ...
```

**0.9.0 and under:**

When you start a job or start the shell change the memory.  We had to modify the spark-shell script so that it would carry command line arguments through as arguments for the underlying java application. In particular:

```
OPTIONS="$@"
...
$FWDIR/bin/spark-class $OPTIONS org.apache.spark.repl.Main "$@"
```

Then we can run our spark shell as follows:

```
spark-shell -Dspark.executor.memory=6g
```

When configuring it for a standalone jar, I set the system property programmatically before creating the spark context and pass the value in as a command line argument (I can make it shorter than the long winded system props then).

```
System.setProperty("spark.executor.memory", valueFromCommandLine)
```

As for changing the default cluster wide, sorry, not entirely sure how to do it properly.

One final point - I'm a little worried by the fact you have 2 nodes with 2GB and one with 6GB.  The memory you can use will be limited to the smallest node - so here 2GB.

Comment: `spark.executor.memory` is the memory used by the application (job), not the memory allocated for the worker.

Comment: Ideally you would set the value in the spark.env.sh file. This allows you to set the default without having to pass in the argument every time you run the shell.

Answer (score 12):

In Spark 1.1.1, to set the Max Memory of workers. 
in conf/spark.env.sh, write this:

```
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=2G
```

If you have not used the config file yet, copy the template file

```
cp conf/spark-env.sh.template conf/spark-env.sh
```

Then make the change and don't forget to source it

```
source conf/spark-env.sh
```

Comment: This worked for me in Spark 1.3.0 (without the export). I did source the spark-env.sh though

Comment: @tristan-wu isn't this specific for yarn?

Answer (score 10):

In my case, I use ipython notebook server to connect to spark. I want to increase the memory for executor.

This is what I do:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf

conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster(CLUSTER_URL).setAppName('ipython-notebook').set("spark.executor.memory", "2g")

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

Comment: I was looking for how to set the memory in ipython for 2 days now, and yours is the only one that worked for me.

Comment: yep, this was the only thing that worked for me to boost myself out of the 1024MB OOM hell! :D

Answer (score 9):

According to [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) you can change the *Memory per Node* with command line argument `--executor-memory` while submitting your application. E.g.

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master spark://master.node:7077 \
  --executor-memory 8G \
  --total-executor-cores 100 \
  /path/to/examples.jar \
  1000
```

I've tested and it works.

Answer (score 1):

The default configuration for the worker is to allocate `Host_Memory - 1Gb` for each worker. The configuration parameter to manually adjust that value is `SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY`, like in your question:

`export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=6g`.

Comment: I get your point, and that's kinda how the question is phrased, but I doubt that is what he wants though judging by what he describes on the master monitor page.

Comment: @massag In my case, each worker only use **512MB** by default. When I add setting `export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=6g`. It does not increate memory for workers. I still see memory for each worker is **512MB** on master monitor page

Comment: The master page shows the worker total memory and the currently used memory by a job. Your workers have 2/2/6Gb of total memory and are currently using 512Mb. That's the task executor's memory usage. To change that use `spark.executor.memory`. See @samthebest answer.

Comment: @massag I want to increate task executor's memory usage. I have added this line `export SPARK_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.executor.memory=6g"` to **spark-env.sh** but it is still **512MB**. What it the right way to do that?

Comment: I have the same issue