# Configuring Executor memory and number of executors per Worker node

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

How to configure the Executor's memory in the Spark cluster. Also, How to configure number of executors per worker node ?

Is there any way to know how much executor's memory is free to cache or persist new RDD's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuring Spark executor memory - use the parameter `spark.executor.memory` or key `--executor-memory` when submitting the job

Configuring number of executors per node depends on which scheduler you use for Spark. In case of YARN and Mesos you don't have a control over this, you can just set the number of executors. In case of Spark Standalone cluster, you can tune `SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES` parameter

You can check the amount of free memory in WebUI of the Spark driver. Refer here [How to set Apache Spark Executor memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26562033/how-to-set-apache-spark-executor-memory) to see why this is not equal to the total executor memory you've set

Comment: Does this mean that in standalone, you cannot have more than 1 executors per worker, so you have to create multiple worker instances?