# How to set Spark executor memory?

Tags: apache-spark

I have set **spark.executor.memory** to **2048m**, and in the UI "Environment" page, I can see this value has been set correctly. But in the "Executors" page, I saw there's only 1 executor and its memory is **265.4MB**. Very strange value. why not 256MB, or just as what I set?

What am I missing here?

Comment: What scheduler are you using? Standalone, Mesos, or YARN? Can you post your submit script and the spark environmental variables set by you?

Comment: Sounds like you're running in Standalone mode. Check @devrimbaris 's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Executors" tab on the UI also includes the driver in the list. Its "executor ID" is listed as `<driver>`. This process is not started by Spark, so it is not affected by `spark.executor.memory`.

- If you start the driver with `spark-submit`, its maximal memory can be controlled by `spark.driver.memory` or `--driver-memory`
- If you start it as a plain old Java program, use the usual `-Xmx` Java flag.

Comment: Good answer. Though, are you sure the driver process is not started by Spark? If not, who or what starts it?

Comment: The driver is your application. You can start it with the plain `java` command. Spark provides the `spark-submit` tool which can also be used to start your application.

Comment: That's what I thought. Since I usually use `spark-submit` to launch *Spark* jobs, your affirmation caught me by surprise. Thanks for the aclaration.

Comment: Thanks. I've rephrased the last sentence to make it more clear which flags/settings are for which method of starting it.

Comment: @DanielDarabos, thanks a lot. I did not notice the 2nd part of your answer and had a hard time setting the value in IDE. `-Xmx` saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the following question for the 265.4MB memory size...

[How to set Apache Spark Executor memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26562033/how-to-set-apache-spark-executor-memory)