# spark 1.2.0 mllib kmeans: Out Of Memory Error

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'am new to spark, and I use KMeans algorithm to cluster a data set, which size is 484M, 213104 dimensions, and my code as follow:

```
val k = args(0).toInt
val maxIter = args(1).toInt
val model = new KMeans().setK(k).setMaxIterations(maxIter).setEpsilon(1e-1).run(trainingData)
val modelRDD = sc.makeRDD(model.clusterCenters)
val saveModelPath = "/home/work/kMeansModel_" + args(0)
if(Files.exists(Paths.get(saveModelPath))) {
  FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File(saveModelPath))
}
modelRDD.saveAsTextFile(saveModelPath)
val loss = model.computeCost(trainingData)
println("Within Set Sum of Squared Errors = " + loss)
```

when I set K = 150, it works, but when I set K = 300, it throws `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` exception. My configuration:

```
--executor-memory 30G --driver-memory 4G --conf spark.shuffle.spill=false --conf spark.storage.memoryFraction=0.1
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to try Spark 1.3? The release notes mention a more performant implementation of KMeans (but could only apply to KMeans||)

Comment: are you using SBT to execute your program? Have you tried allocating more memory for the process?

Comment: I tried allocating more memory, from 20G to 30G, but the issue is still

Answer (score 0):

You should tell us more about the environment. Are you running in a real cluster, or in local mode?

Since you said you are new to Spark, I assume you are just playing around on your local machine. In this case, I think this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071539/how-to-set-spark-executor-memory) can help you.

## Update

Your error is not really OOM, but **heap space** exception. Did you cache your RDD?

Comment: I deploy spark on only one machine, and the worker's configuration as follow: `export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=11 export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=40g`, and I running application with `bin/spark-submit --class "userClustering" --master spark://md-machinelearning0-bgp0.hy01:7077 --executor-memory 30G --driver-memory 4G --conf spark.shuffle.spill=false --conf spark.storage.memoryFraction=0.1  /home/work/downloadDetail.jar`

Comment: yes, I cached the RDD originally and then I try no caching it, but the issue is still. The `spark.storage.memoryFraction=0.1`, executor memogry 30G and the data set size 484M, so the memory used to cache is enough