# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when running the DeepLearning4J MNIST sample

Tags: apache-spark, mnist, deeplearning4j

here is what I'm doing on a single node, local spark cluster:

```
git clone https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-spark-cdh5-examples.git
cd dl4j-spark-cdh5-examples.git
mvn package
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=13g
spark-submit --class org.deeplearning4j.examples.cnn.MnistExample ./target/dl4j-spark-cdh5-examples-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

And here is what I'm getting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Here the full stack traces:

> spark-submit --class org.deeplearning4j.examples.cnn.MnistExample
>   ./target/dl4j-spark-cdh5-examples-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 21:21:13,414 INFO ~
>   Load data....
>
> WARNING: COULD NOT LOAD NATIVE SYSTEM BLAS ND4J performance WILL be
>   reduced Please install native BLAS library such as OpenBLAS or
>   IntelMKL See http://nd4j.org/getstarted.html#open for further details
>
> 21:21:20,571 INFO ~ Build model.... 21:21:20,776 WARN ~ Objective
>   function automatically set to minimize. Set stepFunction in neural net
>   configuration to change default settings. 21:21:20,886 INFO ~ ---
>   Starting network training --- [Stage 0:> (0 + 6) / 6]
>
> [Stage 0:> (0 + 6) / 6]Exception in thread "dispatcher-event-loop-3"
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 21:24:12,358 ERROR ~
>   Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectInputStream.java:2421)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1382)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370) at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:115)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:194)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) 21:24:12,358 ERROR ~
>   Exception in task 5.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 5) java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
>   Java heap space at java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:70)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1670) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1344) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
>   at
>   org.nd4j.linalg.api.buffer.BaseDataBuffer.doReadObject(BaseDataBuffer.java:880)
>   at
>   org.nd4j.linalg.api.buffer.BaseDataBuffer.readObject(BaseDataBuffer.java:868)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1706) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1344) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:74)
>   at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1204)
>   21:24:12,358 ERROR ~ Exception in task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3)
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at
>   java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:70) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1670) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1344) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
>   at
>   org.nd4j.linalg.api.buffer.BaseDataBuffer.doReadObject(BaseDataBuffer.java:880)
>   at
>   org.nd4j.linalg.api.buffer.BaseDataBuffer.readObject(BaseDataBuffer.java:868)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1706) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1344) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:74)
>   at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1204)
>   21:24:12,358 ERROR ~ Exception in task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectInputStream.java:2421)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1382)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370) at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:115)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:194)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) 21:24:12,358 ERROR ~
>   Exception in task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2) java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
>   Java heap space at java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:70)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1670) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1344) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
>   at
>   org.nd4j.linalg.api.buffer.BaseDataBuffer.doReadObject(BaseDataBuffer.java:880)
>   at
>   org.nd4j.linalg.api.buffer.BaseDataBuffer.readObject(BaseDataBuffer.java:868)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1706) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1344) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:74)
>   at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1204)
>   21:24:12,375 ERROR ~ Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task
>   launch worker-5,5,main] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at
>   java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:70) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1670) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1344) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
>   at
>   org.nd4j.linalg.api.buffer.BaseDataBuffer.doReadObject(BaseDataBuffer.java:880)
>   at
>   org.nd4j.linalg.api.buffer.BaseDataBuffer.readObject(BaseDataBuffer.java:868)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1706) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1344) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:74)
>   at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1204)
>   21:24:12,375 ERROR ~ Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task
>   launch worker-3,5,main] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at
>   java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:70) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1670) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1344) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
>   at
>   org.nd4j.linalg.api.buffer.BaseDataBuffer.doReadObject(BaseDataBuffer.java:880)
>   at
>   org.nd4j.linalg.api.buffer.BaseDataBuffer.readObject(BaseDataBuffer.java:868)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1706) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1344) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:74)
>   at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1204)
>   21:24:12,375 ERROR ~ Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task
>   launch worker-2,5,main] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at
>   java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:70) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1670) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1344) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
>   at
>   org.nd4j.linalg.api.buffer.BaseDataBuffer.doReadObject(BaseDataBuffer.java:880)
>   at
>   org.nd4j.linalg.api.buffer.BaseDataBuffer.readObject(BaseDataBuffer.java:868)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1706) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1344) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:74)
>   at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1204)
>   21:24:12,383 ERROR ~ Task 5 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
>   Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job
>   aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most
>   recent failure: Lost task 5.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 5, localhost):
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at
>   java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:70) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1670) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1344) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
>   at
>   org.nd4j.linalg.api.buffer.BaseDataBuffer.doReadObject(BaseDataBuffer.java:880)
>   at
>   org.nd4j.linalg.api.buffer.BaseDataBuffer.readObject(BaseDataBuffer.java:868)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1706) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1344) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:74)
>   at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1204)
>
> Driver stacktrace: at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
>   at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>   at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
>   at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236) at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
>   at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48) at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
>   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832) at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845) at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858) at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929) at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1157) at
>   org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.count(JavaRDDLike.scala:440)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.count(JavaRDDLike.scala:46)
>   at
>   org.deeplearning4j.spark.impl.multilayer.SparkDl4jMultiLayer.fitDataSet(SparkDl4jMultiLayer.java:239)
>   at
>   org.deeplearning4j.examples.cnn.MnistExample.main(MnistExample.java:132)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
>   at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
>   at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121) at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) Caused by:
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at
>   java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:70) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1670) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1344) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
>   at
>   org.nd4j.linalg.api.buffer.BaseDataBuffer.doReadObject(BaseDataBuffer.java:880)
>   at
>   org.nd4j.linalg.api.buffer.BaseDataBuffer.readObject(BaseDataBuffer.java:868)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1706) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1344) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:74)
>   at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1204)
>   21:24:12,769 ERROR ~ Exception in task 4.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 4)
>   org.apache.spark.TaskKilledException at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:204)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) 21:30:18,649 ERROR ~ Uncaught
>   exception in thread Thread-3 org.apache.spark.SparkException: Error
>   sending message [message = StopBlockManagerMaster] at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:118)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:77)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMaster.tell(BlockManagerMaster.scala:225)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMaster.stop(BlockManagerMaster.scala:217)
>   at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.stop(SparkEnv.scala:97) at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$12.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1756)
>   at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1229)
>   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1755) at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$3.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:596)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:267)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:239)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:239)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:239)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1765)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:239)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:239)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:239)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like any other spark job, consider bumping the xmx of the slaves as well as the master.

Spark has 2 kinds of memory: the executor with spark standalone and the executors.

Please see: [How to set Apache Spark Executor memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26562033/how-to-set-apache-spark-executor-memory)

Comment: As I'm running in standalone mode IMHO I had to pass the "--driver-memory 8g" option instead of increasing the heap size of the workers...