# How to tune memory for Spark Application running in local mode

Tags: apache-spark

Running Spark Application with local mode, I used the command, such as:

```
spark-submit --master local[*] my_spark_application.py
```

In this case, dose which mean that my application used all memory of my local computer? Are the other parameters, like driver-memory and executor-memory still working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Setting driver memory is the only way to increase memory in a *local* spark application.

"Since you are running Spark in local mode, setting `spark.executor.memory` won't have any effect, as you have noticed. The reason for this is that the Worker "lives" within the driver JVM process that you start when you start spark-shell and the default memory used for that is 512M. You can increase that by setting `spark.driver.memory` to something higher, for example 5g" from [How to set Apache Spark Executor memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26562033/how-to-set-apache-spark-executor-memory)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which virtual environment tool is used , if you install just spark
without  virtual environment (like docker) it takes your full your local memory ,
So , I recommend to use spark inside docker container which it takes about 220MB (default)

First install docker ;

then , Create container ;

install spark into container .

Comment: Hi, I used virtual machine to create ubuntu environment, and allocated the fixed memory for this system, on which spark is running. In this case, is spark application using all memory?

Comment: No , When you run spark app  like my_spark_application.py  it takes just  executor-memory not all memory exactly Ram memory of your vertual machine

Comment: Wether  I can not allocate fixed memory for the spark application in this case unless using the parameter of executor-memory.  Is there default value of the parameter if I do not configure this?

Comment: Allocate driver memory as well when running in local mode. I've found it to be more useful than executor memory albeit slightly disingenuous in my opinion.

Comment: Hi @Garren, I found same issue with you. But, I am not sure. Could you add new answer to describe this? thanks!