# How to join two tables with aggregation

Tags: sql, arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two pyspark dataframes:

one is:

```
name start end
bob    1   3
john   5   8
```

and second is:

```
day outcome
  1   a
  2   c
  3   d
  4   a
  5   e
  6   c
  7   u
  8   l
```

And i need concat days result for every person, like

```
bob  acd

john  ecul
```

Is it possible to do so in pyspark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use spark-sql.
I used scala, but SQL in pyspark is exactly the same and I believe you can easily transform if there is any difference for pyspark.

Join two dataframes, use collect_list() to get array of outcome, then use concat_ws() to concatenate array to string:

```
val dF1 = Seq(
("bob", 1, 3),
("john",  5, 8)
).toDF("name","start","end")

dF1.createOrReplaceTempView("dF1")

val dF2 = Seq(
(1, "a"),
(2, "c"),
(3, "d"),
(4, "a"),
(5, "e"),
(6, "c"),
(7, "u"),
(8, "l")
).toDF("day","outcome")

dF2.createOrReplaceTempView("dF2")


spark.sql(""" 
select d1.name, concat_ws('',collect_list(d2.outcome)) outcome
from
(select d1.name, e.day 
  from dF1 d1 
       lateral view explode(sequence(d1.start, d1.end)) e as day
)d1
left join dF2 d2 on d1.day=d2.day
group by d1.name
""").show(100, false)
```

**Result:**

```
+----+-------+
|name|outcome|
+----+-------+
|bob |acd    |
|john|ecul   |
+----+-------+
```

Fixing OOM:

```
spark.sql(""" 
select d1.name, concat_ws('',collect_list(d2.outcome)) outcome
from dF1 d1 
left join dF2 d2 on d1.start<=d2.day and  d1.end>=d2.day
group by d1.name
""").show(100, false)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It works, i run out of memory tho, so will do all this stuff in another way. My second df is about 200Mb

Comment: @user453575457 If it is too big, then try second query, it can work directly wo sequece+explode

Comment: Your answer is perfectly correct, but spark has a very poor performance here, i will do that in another way. 100 entries - 10kb in first df, 7Mb in second df - lasts for 40 seconds. With 1000 enties - i gave up waiting after 10 min.  And i have 900k entries in first frame, so no chance it will ever be complete.

Comment: @user453575457 Let me think...  This kind of join when one DF is too big and second is small (you said 200Mb) and non equi-join is used then best join strategy is Broadcast nested loop join.  try to force broadcast join

Comment: @user453575457 Use hint: `select /*+ BROADCASTJOIN (d2) */  d1.name, concat_ws( ...`  And now make sure the executor is of size which will fit broadcasted d2

Comment: Sorry i am not too good in spark, what do you mean - executor is of size? Where do i set it?

Comment: Read answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55964221/2700344  You need to set spark.executor.memory, spark.driver.memory. Start with 2G and increase if necessary. Also you can set driver and executor cores and the number of executors.

Comment: just a local  python script for now, later i want to extend it to many vms, but still has not learned how it should be done

Comment: okay. try to force broadcast join using hint in sql / check EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT should show that broadcast join will be used. Increase executor size if necessary

Comment: Worked like a magic! now 1k finished in 5 min, and even better - i understand now how to spread this stuff on more nodes. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I wonder how the first version works after increasing executor size

Comment: I will test and let you know

Comment: First option doesn't work correctly, i'm struggling to figure out  why, so if any updates - will post here

Answer (score 6):

##### Code

```
df = df1.join(df2, on=(df1.start <= df2.day) & (df1.end >= df2.day))

df = df.groupBy('name').agg(F.collect_list(F.struct('day', 'outcome')).alias('outcome'))
df = df.withColumn('outcome', F.transform(F.array_sort('outcome'), lambda x: x.outcome))
df = df.withColumn('outcome', F.array_join('outcome', ''))
```

##### How this works?

Use a non-equi join method to join the dataframe `df1` with `df2`

```
+----+-----+---+---+-------+
|name|start|end|day|outcome|
+----+-----+---+---+-------+
|bob |1    |3  |1  |a      |
|bob |1    |3  |2  |c      |
|bob |1    |3  |3  |d      |
|john|5    |8  |5  |e      |
|john|5    |8  |6  |c      |
|john|5    |8  |7  |u      |
|john|5    |8  |8  |l      |
+----+-----+---+---+-------+
```

Group the dataframe by `name` and `collect` the pairs of day and outcome. **This step is crucial because the `day` column is required to maintain the order of concatenation**

```
+----+--------------------------------+
|name|outcome                         |
+----+--------------------------------+
|john|[{5, e}, {6, c}, {7, u}, {8, l}]|
|bob |[{1, a}, {2, c}, {3, d}]        |
+----+--------------------------------+
```

Sort the array of pairs and transform to extract the `outcome` values

```
+----+------------+
|name|outcome     |
+----+------------+
|john|[e, c, u, l]|
|bob |[a, c, d]   |
+----+------------+
```

Join the array to get the result

```
+----+-------+
|name|outcome|
+----+-------+
|john|ecul   |
|bob |acd    |
+----+-------+
```

Comment: I got a pretty similar to this answer :)  except I think you don't need to create `sequence` if you do conditional join. 
`df1.join(df2, on=(df1.start <= df2.day) & (df1.end >= df2.day))`

Comment: @Emma Agree, Good point :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer is perfectly right and correct, i can check only one answer tho, so checking the earliest