# Spark Structured Streaming throwing Java OOM immediately

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, databricks

I am trying to build a simple pipeline using Kafka as streaming source to Spark's structured streaming APIs, performing group-by aggregations and persisting the results to HDFS.

But, as soon as I submit the job, I am getting Java heap space error even though the streaming data is very less in volume.

Below is the code in pyspark:

```
allEvents =spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
    .option("subscribe","MyNewTopic") \
    .option("group.id","aggStream") \
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
    .load() \
    .select(col("value").cast("string"))

aaIDF = allEvents.filter(col("value").contains("myNewAPI")).select(from_json(col("value"),aaISchema) \
 .alias("colName")).select(col("colName.eventTime"), col("colName.appId"),col("colName.articleId"),col("colName.locale"),col("colName.impression"))

windowedCountsDF = aaIDF.withWatermark("eventTime","10 minutes") \
    .groupBy("appId","articleId","locale",window("eventTime", "2 minutes")).sum("impression").withColumnRenamed("sum(impression)", "views")


query = windowedCountsDF \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .format("parquet") \
    .option("path", "/CDS/events/JS/agg/" + strftime("%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M", gmtime()) + "/") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/CDS/checkpoint/").start()
```

And below is the exception:

```
17/11/23 14:24:45 ERROR Utils: Aborting task
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.BufferHolder.grow(BufferHolder.java:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter.write(UnsafeRowWriter.java:214)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithKeys$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:315)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:261)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: How do you submit the job? What is `spark-submit` and the options?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski spark-submit --packages 'org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.2.0,org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.1.0,org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.1.1' ./AggEventStructuredStreamListener.py

Comment: Can you check out `jconsole` and see what your memory requirements are for the application (and adjust them accordingly)? I don't see any apparent reason why it could fail. Please note that the `--packages` option includes libraries for different Spark versions - 2.2.0 and 2.1.0‌. Also, you're using `spark-sql-k‌​afka` and `sp‌​ark-streaming-kafka` which I doubt you really need. Get rid of `org.apache.spark:sp‌​ark-streaming-kafka-‌​0-8_2.11:2.1.1`.

Answer (score 2):

Two possible reasons:

1. Your watermark set does not take effect. You should reference the column with `colName.eventTime`.

   > Since no watermark is defined (only defined in other category), old aggregation state is not dropped.
2. You should set a bigger value to `--driver-memory` or `--executor-memory` for Spark.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have appropriate driver and execute memory set while submitting the jobs. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871194/how-to-tune-spark-executor-number-cores-and-executor-memory) gives you a brief idea of how to set these configurations.