# What happens if I allocate all the available cores on the server for spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata

As is well known, It is possible to increase the number of cores when submitting our application. Actually, I'm trying to allocate all available cores on the server for the Spark application. I'm wondering what will happen to the performance? will it reduce or be better than usual?

Comment: Are you running spark application on any cluster manager ?

Comment: I'm running spark application on YARN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing about allocating cores (`--executor-cores`) might come in mind that more cores in an executor means more parallelism, more tasks will be executed concurrently, better performance. But it's not true for spark ecosystem. After leaving 1 core for os and other application running in the worker, Study has shown that it's optimal to allocate 5 cores for each executor.

For example, if you have a worker node with 16 cores, the optimal total executors and cores per executor will be `--num-executors 3` and `--executor-cores 5` (as 5*3=15) respectively.

Not only optimal resource allocation brings better performance, it also depends on how the transformations and actions are done on dataframes. More shuffling of data between different executors hampers in performance.

Answer (score -1):

your operating system always need resource for its bare need.
It good to keep 1 core and 1 GB memory for operating system and for other applications. 
If you allocate all resource to spark then it will not going to improve your performance, your other applications starve for resources.
I think its not better idea to allocate all resources to spark only.
Follow below post if you want to tune your spark cluster
[How to tune spark executor number, cores and executor memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871194/how-to-tune-spark-executor-number-cores-and-executor-memory)