# Limiting Apache Spark CPU Usage

Tags: apache-spark

i am using Apache Spark(standalone mode)  ALS recommendation algorithm with 60 GB of data , the problem is the CPU Spike to 100% when algorithms starts
how can i set limitation CPU usage in spark ?
for example just to use 50% of CPU.

i have tried with less CPU cores , but it doesn't change anything regarding to CPU Usage.

i am running spark in standalone mode in a server with following configuration :

```
#System information :
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard
OS Version:                10.0.14393 N/A Build 14393
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
Cores:                     6
Total Physical Memory:     262,030 MB
Available Physical Memory: 178,164 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  300,942 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 215,377 MB

#Spark 
version 2.4.3

#Java
java version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)
```

and i have setup my spark session with following configs:

```
spark_session = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("ALSRecommendation") \
    .config("spark.driver.memory","60G")\
    .config('spark.cores.max', 5)\
    .config("spark.driver.cores",5)\
    .getOrCreate();
```

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html

Comment: @JohnSmith , i already studied that , it doesn't help . it is about how to set CPU Core , not how to limit it .

Comment: Arash, `spark.cores.max` is a `limit` option. You are limiting it to 5 cores in this context. Please expand on your issue.

Comment: Arash, do you have: Apache Hadoop YARN?

Comment: @JohnSmith , no i am running it in stand alone mode , for testing purpose.

Comment: I hope this thread can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/37871195/4270698

Answer (score 3):

You don't seem to be running in standalone mode (it is actually a clustered mode) but in local mode i.e single JVM.

To manage the number of cores used in local mode, you need to set the master to **"local[max_number_of_cores]"**.

So in your case, this should work as expected:

```
spark_session = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("ALSRecommendation") \
    .master("local[5]") \
    .config("spark.driver.memory","60G")\
    .getOrCreate();
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of CPU, **`spark.executor.cores`** is the amount of concurrent tasks executor can run. More information on [Spark Configuration Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html).

`spark.executor.cores` : *1 in YARN mode, all the available cores on the worker in standalone and Mesos coarse-grained modes.*

**EDIT:** Well, in a standalone cluster Spark only manages application predefined resource configs with provided resource pool. (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html)

Also see this: [How to tune spark executor number, cores and executor memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871194/how-to-tune-spark-executor-number-cores-and-executor-memory)

Comment: since i am running it in standalone mode , there is no need to set spark.executor.cores , also i have tried with that . still spike.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to limit spark's core usage with cgroups but I don't think you'd want to get into that.

Are you running in **cluster** deploy mode?, because 'spark.driver.cores' only takes effect when using cluster deploy mode.

Try to **explicitly** set the amount of cores for the driver and executor:

```
(spark.executor.cores=3)
(spark.driver.cores=2)
```

and get rid of the 'spark.core.max' setting.

Assuming you're only using this host, you should end up with 1 free CPU.
this doesn't solve your issue like you wanted but that's just how spark works.