# Executors and cores in Apache Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn

I'm bit new to Spark and trying to understand few term. (Couldn't understand using online resources)

Please validate me first with below terms:

Executor: Its `container or JVM process` which will be running on `worker node or data node`. We can have multiple Executors per node.

Core: Its a thread within a `container or JVM process` running on `worker node or data node`. We can have multiple cores or threads per executor.

Please correct me If am wrong in above two concepts.

Questions:

1. When ever we submit spark job, What does it means ? Are we handing
   over our job to Yarn or resource manager which will assigning
   resources to my `application or job` in cluster and execute that ?
   Its it correct understanding .. ?
2. In command used to submit job in spark cluster, there is an option
   to set number of executors.

   `spark-submit --class <CLASS_NAME> --num-executors ? --executor-cores ? --executor-memory ? ....`

So these number of executors + cores will be setting up per-node? If not then how can we set specific number of cores per node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your assumptions are correct. For in a detailed explanation regarding cluster architecture please go through [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html#components) link. You'll get a clear picture. Regarding your second question, num-of-executors is for the entire cluster. It is calculated as below:

```
num-cores-per-node * total-nodes-in-cluster
```

For example, suppose that you have a 20-node cluster with 4-core machines, and you submit an application with -executor-memory 1G and --total-executor-cores 8. Then Spark will launch eight executors, each with 1 GB of RAM, on different machines. Spark does this by default to give applications a chance to achieve data locality for distributed filesystems running on the same machines (e.g., HDFS) because these systems typically have data spread out across all nodes.

I hope it helps!

Comment: how can we have multiple executors per node ..? Any setting or configuration  for the same ..?

Comment: Its a cluster configuration. As per your cluster configuration, you can decide the values that need to be passed in spark-submit jobs. See the accepted answer in this link. It has a very good detailed explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871194/how-to-tune-spark-executor-number-cores-and-executor-memory#2%20Answers and do accept the answer once you are satisfied