# Memory Allocation In Spark-Scala Application:

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am executing spark-Scala job using Spark submit command. I have written my code in spark sql where i am joining 2 tables and loading data again in 3rd hive.
code is working fine,But sometimes i am getting some issue like OutofmemoryIssue: Java heap size issue,Timeout error.
So i want to control my job manually by passing number of executors, cores and memory.When i used 16  executor,1 core and 20 GB executor memory my spark application is getting stuck.
can someone please suggest me how should i control manually my spark application by providing correct parameter.and is there any other hive or spark specific parameter are there which i can use for fast execution.

```
    below is configuration of my cluster.



    Number of Nodes: 5
    Number of Cores per Node: 6
    RAM per Node: 125 gb

     Spark Submit Command.
     spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.sparksc \
    --master yarn-client \
   --num-executors 16 \
    --executor-memory 20g \
    --executor-cores 1 \
    examples/jars/spark-examples.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on volume of your data. you can make dynamic parameters. This link has very nice explanation
[How to tune spark executor number, cores and executor memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871194/how-to-tune-spark-executor-number-cores-and-executor-memory)

you can enable spark.shuffle.service.enabled, use spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=400, hive.exec.compress.intermediate=true, hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=536870912, hive.exec.compress.output=true, hive.output.codec=snappy, mapred.output.compression.type=BLOCK

if your data >700MB you can enable spark.speculation properties