# List of spark-submit options

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit

There are a ton of tunable settings mentioned on `Spark` [configurations page](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html). However as told [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-submit-SparkSubmitOptionParser.html), the `SparkSubmitOptionParser` *attribute-name* for a `Spark` property can be different from that *property's-name*.

For instance, `spark.executor.cores` is passed as `--executor-cores` in `spark-submit`.

---

Where can I find an *exhaustive* list of all tuning parameters of `Spark` (along-with their `SparkSubmitOptionParser` property name) that can be passed with `spark-submit` command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While **@suj1th**'s valuable inputs did solve my problem, I'm answering my own question to directly address my query.

---

- You need not look up for `SparkSubmitOptionParser`'s *attribute-name* for a given `Spark` *property* (configuration setting). Both will do just fine. However, do note that there's a subtle difference between there usage as shown below:

  `spark-submit --executor-cores 2`

  `spark-submit --conf spark.executor.cores=2`

  Both commands shown above will have same effect. The second method takes *configurations* in the format `--conf <key>=<value>`.
- Enclosing values in quotes (correct me if this is incorrect / incomplete)

  (i) Values need not be enclosed in quotes (single  `''` or double `""`) of any kind (you still can if you want).

  (ii) If the value has a `space` character, enclose the entire thing in double quotes `""` like `"<key>=<value>"` as shown [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamically-loading-spark-properties).
- For a *comprehensive* list of all *configurations* that can be passed with `spark-submit`, just run `spark-submit --help`
- In [this link](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/docs/submitting-applications.md#loading-configuration-from-a-file) provided by **@suj1th**, they say that:

  > configuration values explicitly set on a SparkConf take the highest
  >   precedence, then flags passed to spark-submit, then values in the
  >   defaults file.
  >
  > If you are ever unclear where configuration options are coming from,
  >   you can print out fine-grained debugging information by **running
  >   spark-submit with the --verbose option.**

---

Following two links from `Spark` docs list a lot of *configuration*s:

- [`Spark` Configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)
- [Running `Spark` on `YARN`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html)

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you should actually load your configurations from a file, as mentioned in this [document](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/docs/submitting-applications.md#loading-configuration-from-a-file), instead of passing them as flags to `spark-submit`. This relieves the overhead of mapping `SparkSubmitArguments` to Spark configuration parameters. To quote from the above document:

> Loading default Spark configurations this way can obviate the need for certain flags to `spark-submit`. For instance, if the spark.master property is set, you can safely omit the `--master` flag from `spark-submit`. In general, configuration values explicitly set on a `SparkConf` take the highest precedence, then flags passed to `spark-submit`, then values in the defaults file.