# Apache Spark: Usage of hardware resources

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying around with a Spark Standalone Cluster. I wanted to setup the cluster settings, that an application always uses as much resources of the cluster as possible. I changed the following settings:

```
spark-defaults.conf (on Master node)
  spark.driver.cores  (works fine)
  spark.driver.memory (works fine)
  spark.executor.cores
  spark.executor.memory
spark-env.sh (on each node, depending on the available hardware)
  SPARK_WORKER_CORES
  SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY
```

Am I right, that each Executor always runs with the same resources since the settings `spark.executor.cores` & `spark.executor.memory` are set globally?

Is there no possibility to set different values per machine to use the resources more efficiently? My cluster has the following hardware:

```
 - Master: 12 CPU Cores & 128 GB RAM (~10 GB RAM / Core)
 - Slave1: 12 CPU Cores &  64 GB RAM (~ 5 GB RAM / Core)
 - Slave2:  6 CPU Cores &  64 GB RAM (~10 GB RAM / Core)
```

As you can see, the RAM/Core value is very different, this seems to be the issue of the problem or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it now - set the following parameters:

```
spark-defaults.conf (on Master):
  spark.executor.memory 60g
  (spark.executor.cores not set! -> executor can use all available -> see setting SPARK_EXECUTOR_CORES below!)
```

As I want to use the "strong" Master node for Driver AND Executor processes, I also set the following:

```
spark-env.sh (on Master):
  SPARK_EXECUTOR_CORES=10 (-> use 10 of the 12 Cores for executors -> the other 2 are planned for the Driver process)
  SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=60g (-> set only 60g, because the setting spark.executor.memory sets the memory also to this size, set here more memory would be a waste of the resource!)

spark-defaults.conf (on Master)
  (spark.executor.memory set as written above (=60g))
  spark.driver.cores 2 (-> use the 2 cores, which aren't use for executors yet)
  spark.driver.memory 10g (can be up to ~60g, as there are only used 60 of 128 GB for the executors)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change `spark-env.sh` `Master` and each slave ( `Executor` node)

Master : `spark-env.sh`

```
SPARK_WORKER_CORES=12
SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=10g
```

Slave 1 : `spark-env.sh`

```
SPARK_WORKER_CORES=12
SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=5g
```

Slave 2 : `spark-env.sh`

```
SPARK_WORKER_CORES=6
SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=10g
```

Have a look at this [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) link for configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I already tried this, the hardware is "reserved" for  the cluster, but there's still only 1024m per node (=worker)! If I increase this value via spark.executor.memory, every executor has the same memory amount - but this won't utilize the whole hardware resources (because of the 64 vs 128 GB RAM)

Comment: This should work. I have found related question just now : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24242060/how-to-change-memory-per-node-for-apache-spark-worker. Have a look into it.

Comment: There's also the problem, that each executor gets the same amount of memory, e.g. 60g. So my Slave1 & Slave2 would be utilized, but not my Master instance (only 60g of 120g used)!

Comment: set spark.driver.memory   for master in spark default configuraiton